# Can the kind `*` be thought of as `ob(Hask)`?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

If **Hask** is the category of all haskell types (with functions as arrows), then can we think of `ob(Hask)` (that is, the collection of objects of **Hask**) as equal to `*`?

If not, in what sense is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point it must be some sort of cliché to link to the [Hask article on the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask) every time a question about Hask gets brought up, but here it is.

To expand on the wiki a little I think the answer to this question is a very boring yes, but only because Hask is *defined* such that the objects of Hask are types of kind ⭑. The full definition is:

- Let every type of kind ⭑ be an object of Hask, except `undefined`. I think "Yes" is essentially the answer to your question until a devil's advocate brings up `undefined` and `seq`, at which point the answer necessarily becomes more and more complicated.
- Let every function of type `A -> B` be an arrow from the object corresponding to type `A` to the object corresponding to type `B`.
- Very carefully [choose a notion of equality for the arrows, which may or may not exist](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/) ([see ensuing discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4wk0gs/hask_is_not_a_category/)) or maybe throw out `seq` or maybe give up altogether.
- Let the arrow corresponding to `id :: A -> A` be the identity arrow for each object.
- Let `.`, which is associative &c., correspond to the composition of arrows, which must be associative &c.

This is by no means the only category you can model Haskell programs with but we do this and bless it with the Hask name because a lot of other notions then naturally correspond to Haskell computation. For example, an endofunctor on this category would conveniently be represented by something of kind ⭑ -> ⭑ with a (lawful) function taking `fmap :: ((a :: ⭑) -> (b :: ⭑)) -> ((f a :: ⭑) -> (f b :: ⭑))`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there are types of kind other than `*` in Haskell with `DataKinds` that won't be part of your **Hask** category.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
data Foo = Bar
```

`'Bar`'s kind is `Foo`, so you can't use `->` with it, so it would be outside your **Hask** but still a Haskell type.